# HTTP POST individual fields

Tags: node.js

Following [this beginner tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/), how to get the individual fields, like in php - `$_POST['flda']` without additional layers\libs?

HTML

```
​<form method="POST" action="/show">
   <input type="test" name="flda" />
   <input type="test" name="fldb" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

NodeJS

```
request.addListener ( "data", function ( data )
{
   console.log ( "Received POST data:'" + data + "'.\n" );
});
```

Result

> Received POST data:'flda=field1+Data&fldb=field2+Data'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`querystring`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq) module included with Node.js.

```
var qs = require("querystring");
```

And within your request handler:

```
var form = qs.parse(data);
```